# ConsumerTemplate: indicate that receive endpoint should not be cached since it is dynamic

Tags: grails, groovy, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am attempting to set up a quartz job which executes a ConsumerTemplate.receive using a dynamic endpoint (related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676088/having-trouble-getting-jms-activemq-selector-syntax-with-consumertemplate-rece) question).

From my googling and source code peaking, I see that the ConsumerTemplate will attempt to cache my endpoint, but since it is dynamic that could lead to an OutOfMemoryException and in any case there is no reason to cache a dynamic endpoint. (see http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/camel-users/201003.mbox/%3C75bda7a01003222327i456bf92egd37e1d4868d06041@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Is there anyway to indicate that an endpoint should not be cached by the ConsumerTemplate, perhaps an option on the endpoint URI? I see there is a way to set the cache size globally ( https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/How+do+I+configure+the+default+maximum+cache+size+for+ProducerCache+or+ProducerTemplate ), but I don't think I want to do that since I have several static consumers which probably benefit from the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a consumer template from the API on CamelContext where you can specify a cache limit. http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#createConsumerTemplate(int).

Comment: Great, this looks like it will do the trick. Question about usage: I am creating a new consumer template on every run of a quartz job, would it be best practice to wrap my code in a try / finally block and call `stop()` on the consumer template in the finally block (I'm worried about some kind of resource leak...)?

Comment: Yeah if you are not going to re-use that endpoint again in the future. Or if there is a long time before you will reuse it again.

Comment: What would an example be of an endpoint uri you use with the template? As some Camel components allows to be reused by to specify a specific action/file etc to consume. This avoids creating to many consumers and resources. But allows to reuse base consumer instead.

Comment: I'm using and ActiveMQ endpoint with a dynamic selector in the URI (like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13676088/236255)